# Unable to write the data into newline in csv file for dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, flask-restplus

Hello guys I have a data which in datadrame i want to dump that data into csv file but i'm getting the all the data in one line i'm not getting how to make it happen **please guys its a request don't make it duplicate please answer it where i'm doing wrong** this is my data:

```
Asset_Id   Asset Family     Asset Name  Location      Asset Component
3          Nano Dial Assem  NDA11       Zenoa         Fusion Tank                   
1          Haptic Analy HAL3Technopolis Rotation Chamber  Rotation Chamber      
2          Hyperdome Insp   HISP2       Zenoa         Turbo Quantifier  
4          Geometric Synth  GeoSyn25    La Puente     Ion Gas Diffuser              
1          Haptic Analy HAL1Zenoa       Tetris Measuring  Unit  Measurement             
2          Hyperdome Insp   HISP1       Technopolis   Laser Column              
3          Nano Dial Assem  NDA14       Zenoa         Wave Generator                    
4          Geometric Synth  GeoSyn24    La Puente     Progeometric Plane
```

**"data" contains the values which i have shown above**.This is the lines of i have written and please edit the same code

```
 data = dataGen.compute(uploaded_file, recordCount)
     #Output the generated data to the browser
     proxy = io.StringIO()
     writer = csv.writer(proxy)
     writer.writerow(data.to_records(index=False))

     # Creating the byteIO object from the StringIO Object
     mem = io.BytesIO()
     mem.write(proxy.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
      # mem.write(proxy.getvalue())

      # seeking was necessary. Python 3.5.2, Flask 0.12.2
     mem.seek(0)

     return send_file(
             mem,
             as_attachment=True,
             attachment_filename='test.csv',
             mimetype='text/csv'
                )
```

please help me how to get that data into newline i'm getting all the data in one line or any edit is suggested please tell me....thnx

Comment: @user5173426 it should be in csv file with new line you can refer the data i have given

Comment: First of all, nobody _makes_ sth a duplicate, people only see very similar up to equal questions and then _mark_ sth as duplicate. This is nothing bad for you, because ideally you simply would have a link to many answers including an already accepted one. However, if you want to have meaningful feedback, plase try to do also some efforts in creating a well understandable question. And this begins with using punctuation so that people can tell at least one sentence from the next and does definitely include code which is also understandable and does not use several undefined functions.

Comment: So you want the data in a new csv with a line break?

Comment: @user5173426 yes but i have other way to do it but i want do it same way i have written my is it possible?

Comment: @SpghttCd i understand but i want to get it in same code i'm using flask RestPLUS api where im getting the csv file to download with all data actually i got the file with the name of test.csv but it containing all data into same line

Comment: okbutstilltheresnomcveinyourpostnobodycantestyourcodesampleandyoudidntevenmentionflaskatleastyoucouldhaveaddedaflasktagandadditionallyyoudidntevenmentionyouhaveanalternativewaytodoitbutwantitthatwaywherebythewayareasonwouldhelpunderstanding.........

Comment: @SpghttCd i got it edited

Comment: Ok, is `data` a pandas dataframe? So you perhaps know about `data.to_csv()` Describe what you want to achieve and how you try to do it. And provide a _minimal_ but still _running_ example, this is called a [mcve]. What is `dataGen`? What is `send_file`? Never heard of that. Why this io/StringIO/BytesIO stuff? This _not_ self explaining - so please revise your question.

Comment: rahul singh. Please define the data type that holds 'data'. Is it a string,list,etc?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to write a CSV file to memory and then use `send_file()` with the memory version. You should be able to use [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) to write the data directly in CSV format as follows:

```
df = dataGen.compute(uploaded_file, recordCount)

mem = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(mem, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
mem.seek(0)

return send_file(
    mem,
    as_attachment=True,
    attachment_filename='test.csv',
    mimetype='text/csv'
)
```